# Why Java uses en_AU (English, Australia) for language codes but other technologies uses en-AU (dash, not underscore)?

Tags: java, internationalization

I am puzzled by this situation.

In Java, language codes use, if needed, underscores such as in en_AU. But I see in other places and packages (such as JQuery UI), people use dashes as in en-au.

I am interested in know why there is this difference.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Historical, java used some constant names, hence in the names had to use an underscore, not minus. It swept over to the string values. As opposed to Java usage in Font: "Arial-PLAIN-10". So a programmer short-sightedness.

BTW the '-' is now allowed in Java too, at least for variants.

One can use `Locale.forLanguageTag("en-AU")`.